# Send email with Mailgun with Javascript

Tags: javascript, rest, sendmail, mailgun

I'm working with JS and I have the follow code:

```
  var XHRResponse = XHR.send("POST", "https://api.mailgun.net/v2/sandbox224f28ae45a8499d84184fd4c48e62ee.mailgun.org/messages",{
    "parameters": {
      "from": "Mailgun Sandbox <postmaster@sandbox224f28ae45a8499d84184fd4c48e62ee.mailgun.org>",
      "to": "Jordi <myname@gmail.com>",
      "subject": "Hello Jordi",
      "text": "Congratulations Jordi, you just sent an email with Mailgun!  You are truly awesome!  You can see a record of this email in your logs: https://mailgun.com/cp/log .  You can send up to 300 emails/day from this sandbox server.  Next, you should add your own domain so you can send 10,000 emails/month for free."
    }
  });
```

I need to authenticate with the apikey but i don't know where and how.

Thanks

Comment: See this for authentication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507234/how-to-use-basic-auth-with-jquery-and-ajax

Answer (score 10):

Mailgun API documentation has the entirety of this information. Look at the Authentication section specifically, http://documentation.mailgun.com/api-intro.html#authentication. However with that being said, I wouldn't run this in the client if they, and if I understood correctly, require the key to be written in plain text.